# File to import not found or unreadable: bulma-extensions/extensions. with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, sass, bulma

Encounter error when importing bulma extentions like this `@import 'bulma-extensions/extensions';`. I was able to import bulma this way `@import 'bulma/bulma';` so I was wondering why I can't do that with bulma-extensions. I am using `ReactJS` by the way. I'd like to know it I am the one doing something wrong or it's a common error when integrating `sass` with `react` because `bulma` works well with other frameworks e.i. `Vuejs/Angular`.

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "D:/Study/Andro/admin-exchange/src/index.scss",
  "line": 2,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: bulma-extensions/extensions.",
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma-extensions/extensions.\n        on line 2 of src/index.scss\n>> @import 'bulma-extensions/extensions';\n\n   ^\n"
}
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "D:/Study/Andro/admin-exchange/src/index.scss",
  "line": 2,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: bulma-extensions/extensions.",
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma-extensions/extensions.\n        on line 2 of src/index.scss\n>> @import 'bulma-extensions/extensions';\n\n   ^\n"
}
```

> Note: I understand that I can do it like this `@import '../node_modules/bulma-extensions/dist/css/bulma-extensions.sass';` but that is not without changing the path for each extension inside the file as well for it to work.

Comment: are you trying to import `.sass` in into `.scss`?

Comment: I'm trying to import all bulma-extensions in my index.scss like this `@import 'bulma-extensions/extensions';` but encounter the error and when I did `@import '../node_modules/bulma-extensions/dist/css/bulma-extensions.sass';` it works but not without also changing the path for importing the extensions in that file which are all .sass as well.(Example: `@import "bulma-accordion/src/sass/index.sass"` changed to `@import "./../../bulma-accordion/src/sass/index.sass"` otherwise it will not be found as well.)

Comment: Does the error occur because of that, because I am importing .sass files into .scss file? But why is it that when I did the later it works?